# strftime codes vs GetLocaleInfo codes

Tags: windows, winapi, datetime

I need to format a date based on the locale in Windows. For this purpose I use GetLocaleInfo with LOCALE_SSHORTDATE parameter.

Get LocaleInfo returns M/d/yyyy. But I cannot pass this to strftime because strftime codes are different. It would be %m/%d/%y.

Is there any quicker way to achieve this? Assume that I am not using MFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GetDateFormatEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318088%28VS.85%29.aspx) function together with [GetLocaleInfoEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318103%28VS.85%29.aspx) if needed. In the way you can format the data better as with MFC.

Comment: Thanks. This has helped. I rather chose to use GetDateFormat because the Ex version does not work on XP OS.